# Intellij Flutter: ld: can't write output file for architecture x86_64

Tags: flutter, macos, intellij-idea

Intellij Flutter: ld: can't write output file: /Users/myname/IdeaProjects/flutter_ssi_app/myapp/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myname for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have rights problematics on your build directory.
You can reset it without fear.

`sudo rm -rf build`